# Bootstrap Carousel - Show different images per slide through PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a carousel in which each images will come from my PHP database. However, each slide just show the same thing. Not sure what loop to include since there is already a 'while' statement.

My database structure is this.

The table name is 'items'
column 1 - id
column 2 - name
column 3 - image

What I'm trying to achieve is for every slide to show the 'image' of every 'id.

Example:
id #1 - potato.jpg
id #2 - tomtato.jpg
and so on...

The code is below.

function display_carousel(){
  global $conn;

```
    echo "<div id='myCarousel' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>

              <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
                <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='0' class='active'></li>
                <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='1' class='active'></li>
              </ol>

              <div class='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>";

                    $sql = "SELECT image FROM items";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                      extract($row);

                          echo "<div class='item active'>
                            <img src='$image' alt='Image'>
                               <div class='carousel-caption'>
                                <h3>CAPTION</h3>
                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class='item'>
                            <img src='$image' alt='Image'>
                               <div class='carousel-caption'>
                                <h3>CAPTION</h3>
                              </div>
                          </div>";
                  }
   echo "</div>";

      echo "<a class='left carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='prev'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class='right carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='next'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
                </a>
      </div>";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to make sure what you are getting out of your database is what you think it is by using a var_dump().  Just make sure you are not getting three of the same images from there.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```